# PHP loop, change last item?

Tags: php, loops, css-selectors

This might actually be a css question but I'm hoping not because I'd like this to work in IE.

I have the following loop:

```
<?php 
  if ($category)
{
     foreach($category as $item)
         {
               echo $item['name'];
               echo ", ";
         }
} ?>
```

Which should output

item, item, item, item,

The only thing is...I'd like to NOT have a comma after the last item. Is there any way to do this within a loop?

Comment: `echo if ($category)` is wrong btw. Just `if ($category)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well to keep your code how it is, you could add a counter, and skip the last one.

```
<?php 
if ($category) {
     $counter = 0;
     foreach($category as $item)
         {
               $counter++;
               echo $item['name'];
               if ($counter < count($category)) {
                   echo ", ";
               }
         }
}
?>
```

Or you can do it much, much, quicker:

```
<?php echo implode(", ", array_map(create_function('$item', 'return $item["name"];'), $category)); ?>
```

Comment: +1 for `implode` (but your code has some error regarding quotes). Better is to cache the value of `count()` (I think).

Comment: Why the `create_function`? `implode` seems to do what the OP wants without all that junk...

Comment: @Billy ONeal: that's what I thought, then I realized it's because it has to be `$item['name']`, not just `$item`.

Comment: @Felix King: Thanks for that Felix.  I used the single quotes from the example given on the key, not paying attention to the fact I was already in single quotes.  A common issue when using `create_function()` for me, as I tend to use single quotes for keys.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: As @Jonah Bron says, there is the need to access a sub-component, hence the map.  Accessing a particular component of an array is so common, it would be nice if there was a built-in map function that did that.

Comment: I like the implode...but I don't know if I know enough php to spot the errors with the quotes? Will try it for sure!

Comment: @redconservatory: The error was only there for a little while, once I was notified it was edited out.

Answer (score 4):

Don't echo immediately but save your output into a variable that you can trim.

```
<?php 
if ($category) {
    $output = '';
    foreach($category as $item) {
           $output .= $item['name'];
           $output .= ", ";
    }
    echo rtrim($output, ', ');
} 
?>
```

Comment: Nice, using `rtrim()`, clearer than the `preg_replace()` and `substr()` methods.

Comment: Actually substr() is much faster because it doesn't have to know anything. All it has to know it's given (a string and 2 numbers). rtrim() has to search. preg_replace is just crazy

Comment: @Rudie: I never said *faster*, I said *clearer*, which in the case of the microseconds that operation takes, is most likely more important in the code.

Answer (score 2):

The `implode` solution is the simplest, but you asked for a loop. This method avoids putting an extra conditional in the loop, and therefore should be somewhat more efficient. Basically, instead of doing something different for the last item, you do something different for the first item.

```
$myArray = array(); //Fill with whatever
$result = $myArray[0];
for ($idx = 1; $idx < count($myArray); $idx += 1)
{
    $result .= ', ' . $myArray[$idx];
}
```

EDIT: After realizing you want $item['name'] instead of just $item:

```
$myArray = array(); //Fill with whatever
$result = $myArray[0]['name'];
for ($idx = 1; $idx < count($myArray); $idx += 1)
{
    $result .= ', ' . $myArray[$idx]['name'];
}
```

Comment: Oops, needs to be `for ($idx = 1; $idx < count($myArray); $idx += 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

As lovely as `foreach` is,...

```
<?php
if ($category) {
     $count = count($category) - 1;
     for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
         echo $category[$i]['name'];
         if ($i < $count)
             echo ', ';
     }
}
?>
```

...`for` is sometimes necessary.

Comment: A `for` isn't necessary here. See Orbling's answer. In fact, a loop isn't necessary at all in this case.

Comment: @Treeface: The OP specifically asked "Is there any way to do this within a loop?"

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Yes, but he probably didn't really mean " _it must be in a loop_ ".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$category` is an array, you can use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to get what you want:

**Edit:**  Missed the $categories['name'] part, this should work:

```
<?php implode(", ", array_keys($category, 'name')); ?>
```

Comment: That would work well, but he needs to output `$item['name']`, not just `$item`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what `array_keys` does. It won't give you the value of `$item['name']`. Also note that `$categories` is at least a 2-dimensional array. It is an arra if items and each item is an array that contains at least the entry `name`.

Comment: @galador That use of `array_keys()` is quite cool, but 'name' is in the sub-array, not the top-level.

Comment: @Orbling: Even if it was in top-level, `array_keys` works differently: `array_keys($category, 'name')` will give you all the keys of the elements in `$category` with the **value** `name`. So e.g. applied to `array('name', 'foo', 'bar', 'name')` it would return `array(0, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution to the "last comma" problem is to put items into an array and then implode it:

```
 $temp = array();
 foreach($category as $item)
    $temp[] =  $item['name'];
 echo implode(', ', $temp);
```

If you want this more generic, you can also write a function that picks ("plucks") a specific field out of each subarray:

```
  function array_pluck($ary, $key) {
     $r = array();
     foreach($ary as $item)
         $r[] = $item[$key];
     return $r;
  }
```

and then just

```
  echo implode(', ', array_pluck($category, 'name'));
```

Comment: That's a good name for the function I was describing as required in PHP in the comments to my answer.  Hence why I use the map.  Good though. +1

Answer (score 0):

And another option:

```
<?php 
$out = "";

foreach ($category as $item)
    {
    $out .= $item['name']. ", ";
    }

$out = preg_replace("/(.*), $/", "$1", $out);
echo $out;
?>
```

Comment: Was the `preg_replace` really all that much easier than `substr($out, 0, -2)`?

Comment: Oops, needs to be `$out = preg_replace("/(.*), /", '$1', $out);`.  The other solutions seem more efficient anyway though... plus `substr` would probably be better than regex.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: yeah, because I never remember the params of `substr` :) Anyway it will be really rare to find an instance in which you'll find an appreciable difference between the two.

Comment: @nico: maybe, but using `substr` (or `rtrim` as in @rjk' answer) is much more obvious in it's intent.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, @Jonah Bron: The regexp is many times clearer than the `substr()`, though is in need of a `$`.  A much clearer regexp in this instance would be `preg_replace("/, $/", "", $out)`.

Comment: Actually putting the comma before the value and than using substr($out, 2) is even faster

Answer (score 0):

Or you could check for the last key:

```
end($category);
$lastkey = key($category);
foreach ( $category AS $key => $item ) {
  echo $item['name'];
  if ( $lastkey != $key ) {
    echo ', ';
  }
}
```